# Allow Element to Overflow Above

Tags: html, css

I am trying to allow an element to overflow in the y-direction above it's parent.

Sandbox: http://www.cssdesk.com/j7yGc

```css
#main {
  background: white;
  width: 400px;
  left: 500px;
  top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

#abv {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

#blw {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: red;
}

#inner {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  left: 100px;
}

#row {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <div id='abv'>
    Above
  </div>
  <div id='blw'>
    Below
    <div>
      Row 1
    </div>
    <div>
      Row 2
    </div>
    <div id='row'>
      Row 3
      <div id='inner'>
        Inner
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      Row 4
    </div>
    <div>
      Row 5
    </div>
    <div>
      Row 6
    </div>
    <div>
      Row 7
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `row` element has an `inner` element within it, which it offset by 50 pixels upwards. I want the `inner` element to scroll with the `row` element (so they are always 50 pixels apart). If the `row` element is scrolled upwards, and the `inner` element overlaps with the `abv` element, I want the `inner` element to be displayed on top of it, meaning it is always visible.

In the current state of the code, the `inner` element disappears behind the `abv` element if you scroll down, and there is an empty space between Rows 3 and 4, which I would like gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the row element is scrolled upwards, and the inner element overlaps with the abv element,  I want the inner element to be displayed on top of it, meaning it is always visible.

You have declared `overflow: scroll` on the `#blw` selector so the content is clipped (not rendered outside the padding box). See [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) (MDN).

> there is an empty space between Rows 3 and 4

This is because the element is still "in-flow", but offset from it's containing block. See [Visual formatting model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Visual_formatting_model) (MDN).

Possible solution:

```css
#abv {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative; /* NEW */
  z-index: 1; /* NEW */
}
#blw {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: red;
  padding-top: 100px; /* NEW */
  position: relative; /* NEW */
  top: -100px; /* NEW */
}
#inner {
  position: absolute; /* CHANGED */
  top: -50px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 2; /* NEW */
}
```